# Mapbox GL Expression to filter array in property

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have GeoJSON Feature properties that look like this:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
        "id": "someID",
        "lines": [
          {
            "name": "Foo",
            "anotherProperty": 1
          },
          {
            "name": "Bar",
            "anotherProperty": 2
          }
        ]
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            5.9765625,
            48.45835188280866
          ],
          [
            40.42968749999999,
            47.517200697839414
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And I'd like to select features that match `'name': 'Foo'` in their `lines` array. But I'm struggling to write a match expression that will check each entry in `'lines'`.